# Running open recursive DNS Server

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, dns

I have built a custom DNS Front end that basically replicates what OpenDNS is offering. At the moment it is fire walled and customers have to log in so I get there IP and dynamically update the firewall.

I want to turn this into an Open DNS but I know if I do Amazon will shutdown my service pretty quick. My information is that I can approach amazon and get this changed but I will need to have a good plan for attacks and blocking connections.

If I run my own DNS server and dont do any recursion is this safer for attacks? Any information on setting this up will be greatly appreciated.

Cheers.

Comment: How do you "know" and why do you think Amazon would shut you down for providing a service on the Internet? Approach Amazon and get *what* changed? Also, why would not doing recursion even make sense in this context? The point of what OpenDNS provides *is recursive lookups*.

Comment: I have have UDP Port 53 blocked before by amazon when I had it open and doing recursive queries. I was thinking I could ask them no to block it if they detected based on my having the correct security in place.

Comment: I have been looking at setting bind up to respond iterativly but I cannot seem to get the configuration right. I understand OpenDNS does this but they have alot more money that I do. I intend to run a cache and then if I dont have the domain in the cache I can iterativly respond to the client so the client goes elsewhere.

Comment: I'm unclear why AWS would block that, unless they thought you had set up a recursive resolver by mistake.  If you cache DNS lookups, be sure you honor the TTL you receive; otherwise you'll be potentially causing problems for the sites you're caching.  Also be aware that your clients need to use a server in an AWS region near them, since many sites return different DNS query results based on the geolocation of the requester, determined by the requester's IP address.  These sites will actually respond to your server's location, not your client's.